# не работает свойство transition на объекте с абсолютным позиционированием

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.querySelector('.Container').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.Container').style.left = '450px'
}
document.querySelectorALL('.Container')[1].onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.Container').style.left = '0px'
}
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  transition: left 7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <a href="#" id="text-1">We just help you become happier</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы можете код нормально вставить, а то немного не понятно. [Вот справка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Нет такого метода `querySelectorALL`, есть `querySelectorAll`

Comment: Хз в чем проблема по идее должно по системе ease-in-out двигаться 7сек направо 450px. А сейчас делает резко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо установить начальное значение свойства `left`.

```js
document.querySelector('.Container').onclick = function() {
  document.querySelector('.Container').style.left = '450px'
}
```

```css
.Container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  width: 700px;
  height: 600px;
  transition: left 7s ease-in-out;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <a href="#" id="text-1">We just help you become happier</a>
</div>
```